Twin.macro not making use of SSR with Next.JS 14
I'm using Twin.macro with Next.JS 14, NX and emotion. I've followed the example of Twin.macro and either I keep running into errors as v8 doesn't exist or Twin.macro is executed at run time
What am I trying to do? use SSR with Twin.macro
What is happening? Twin.macro is executed at run time/
My question? How can I reconfigure my code to use SSR.
next.config.mjs
//@ts-check

import { composePlugins, withNx } from '@nx/next';
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm';
import createMDX from '@next/mdx';
import { withSentryConfig } from '@sentry/nextjs';
import withTwin from './withTwin.mjs';

/**
 * @type {import('@nx/next/plugins/with-nx').WithNxOptions}
 **/
const nextConfig = {
  typescript: {
    // !! WARN !!
    // Dangerously allow production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has type errors.
    // !! WARN !!
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
  nx: {
    // Set this to true if you would like to to use SVGR
    // See: https://github.com/gregberge/svgr
    svgr: false,
  },
  env: {
    STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY,
    GRAPHQL_URL: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL,
    GRAPHQL_URL_WS: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL_WS,
    APP_URL: process.env.APP_URL,
    BE_URL: process.env.BE_URL,
  },
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'md', 'mdx', 'ts', 'tsx'],

  swcMinify: false, // Ensure SWC is used for minification

  images: {
    domains: [],
  },
  // reactStrictMode: true,
  compiler: {
    // For other options, see https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/nextjs-compiler#emotion
    emotion: true,
  },
};

const withMDX = createMDX({
  // Add markdown plugins here, as desired
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  // @ts-ignore
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
    rehypePlugins: [],
  },
});

const sentryWebpackPluginOptions = {
  // Additional config options for the Sentry webpack plugin. Keep in mind that
  // the following options are set automatically, and overriding them is not
  // recommended:
  //   release, url, configFile, stripPrefix, urlPrefix, include, ignore

  org: 's',
  project: '',

  // An auth token is required for uploading source maps.
  authToken: process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,

  silent: true, // Suppresses all logs

  // For all available options, see:
  // https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin#options.
};

const plugins = [
  // Add more Next.js plugins to this list if needed.
  // @ts-ignore
  (nextConfig) => withSentryConfig(nextConfig, sentryWebpackPluginOptions),
  withNx,
  withMDX,
  withTwin,
];
// @ts-ignore
export default composePlugins(...plugins)(nextConfig);


.babelrc
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "babel-plugin-macros"
      ],
      [
        "@emotion/babel-plugin",
        {
          "sourceMap": true,
          "autoLabel": "dev-only",
          "labelFormat": "[local]",
          "cssPropOptimization": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
  

withTwin.mjs
// @ts-check
import babelPluginTypescript from '@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript';
import babelPluginMacros from 'babel-plugin-macros';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as url from 'url';
import babelPluginTwin from 'babel-plugin-twin';

const __dirname = url.fileURLToPath(new URL('.', import.meta.url));

// The folders containing files importing twin.macro
const includedDirs = [
  path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../../libs/ui-web/src'),
];

/** @returns {import('next').NextConfig} */
export default function withTwin(
  /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
  nextConfig
) {
  return {
    ...nextConfig,
    webpack(
      /** @type {import('webpack').Configuration} */
      config,
      options
    ) {
      config.module = config.module || {};
      config.module.rules = config.module.rules || [];

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(tsx|ts)$/,
        include: includedDirs,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMaps: options.dev,
              plugins: [
                babelPluginTwin, // Optional
                [
                  babelPluginMacros,
                  {
                    twin: {
                      config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js'),
                    },
                  },
                ],
                [babelPluginTypescript, { isTSX: true }],
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      });

      if (typeof nextConfig.webpack === 'function')
        return nextConfig.webpack(config, options);

      return config;
    },
  };
}


Answer can be found here:
Module not found: Can't resolve 'v8' In NextJS with Twin Macro
